# Software for web filtering and blocking certain sites

Tags: internet, monitoring, web-filtering

I am looking for some software that would be used for blocking certain sites on the internet. The main things I would like to block are

- pornographic sites
- gambling sites
- games sites

It will be used on Windows XP and not on a domain. I looked at a program called Browse Control but that seemed a bit expensive. Web filtering is the main feature that I need. The PCs are in a location that cannot be supervised the whole time and I don't want people going onto dodgy site that they are not meant to be on.

Comment: upvoted because I think you were downvoted for stupid selfish reasons.

That being said: Why are you limiting the users? I see that you can't supervise them, but why aren't they allowed to go on those sites? Are they minors? Are these work computers and you're worried about productivity? This info could help inform the answers.

Comment: its at a drugs and achohol counsoling Charity and to be blunt we cannot trust them along on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at something like [NetNanny](http://www.netnanny.com/)

From their site:

> Internet Filtering
>
> Net Nanny can block not only pornography, but hate sites, questionable
>   chat rooms and other dangers of the Internet. You can configure Net
>   Nanny to block online game and gambling sites, and even make it so
>   your children can only install and play computer games with parental
>   ratings that you deem appropriate.
>
> Net Nanny even offers a simple, easy to use set-up assistant to help
>   parents determine what online activities (Web sites, chat, gaming and
>   social networks) are appropriate based on your family member’s age.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you check out K9 Web Protection. It's similar to NetNanny, but it's freeware (There is a small fee if you are using it for company use and not personal use). The website is below, check it out. Hope it helps!

http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to use OpenDNS. You can go to www.opendns.com and setup a free account. The next thing to do is to configure your router to use the http://OpenDNS.com DNS numbers. Next go to your account and select the web site categories that you don not want them going to and select apply. That's it! When someone tries to go to a web site that you have selected to block they will get a message that they are not allowed to go their. Its a free service from OpenDNS and I use it at several client offices and it works great, no software to load just set the DNS numbers. At the web site they show how to setup a single machine or how to set your router for network protection.

Comment: DNS filtering is too coarse-grained. For example, [there is ASCII porn on textfiles.com](http://artscene.textfiles.com/asciiart/). Now, do you block textfiles.com or not?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what Joe already said, there are some applications out there. I'd recommend the following articles:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content-control_software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-control_software

The first one will get you a list of things to try, along with sites to download them and get more information. The second is of special interest because it'll bring up some points you may not have thought about, including legal issues you may come across. At one point, I worked for a State University, and we were not allowed to filter or restrict web access as the state was burdened with enforcing first amendment rights. If someone complained about another person's use of the web, we had to move the complainant to somewhere they couldn't see the offender's screen.

This was to avoid a lawsuit against the school, but seemed counter-intuitive at the time. Of course, this rule only applied if the people were adults, so keep that in mind.

In your case (as you've answered that you a drugs and alochol counseling charity), I'd say you should get a filter that allows you to block specifically drugs and alcohol-related content in addition to "adult" themed content.