# Blocking access to the Facebook site only, not share and/or like buttons on other pages

Tags: facebook

I want to block Facebook (the Facebook site) for concentrating purposes, but I don't want to break the share or like buttons on other pages (like a good article or a nice clip on YouTube I want to like or share). How can I do that? I use both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Have you thought about using a GreaseMonkey script that just redirects you away from facebook.com to about:blank or google?

Comment: [stayfocused](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) or [rescuetime](https://www.rescuetime.com/tour) come to mind

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software for web filtering and blocking certain sites](http://superuser.com/questions/338604/software-for-web-filtering-and-blocking-certain-sites)

Comment: @masgo: GreaseMonkey is good, but I think it need a little coding...

Comment: @techie007: no it doesn't. Your link is about absolutely blocking. I need something only partly.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Yes, Rescuetime is the one I need. I have spent a month to find it is very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/tour) can do this for you -

> Block Distracting Sites
>
> Do you ever wish you could just turn off the distracting parts of the
>   Internet? Now you can. Choose an amount of time you would like to
>   focus and RescueTime will block access to distracting websites.